# how to use git repos inside another git project without Gitsubmodule or subtree

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have two git repositories `main-pro` and another git repo `plugins`
I use main-pro as my core and `plugin` to components.

I don't want to use the git-submodule anymore because every change in the `plugin` repo will show in the `main-pro's` change list. I don't want to keep any relationship between these two repos, because the `plugin` repo is only for the development environment so I have many things to push pull on both repos, sometime it shows conflict from the plugin repo in the main-pro.

**I dont want to keep the latest commit-id of the plugin repo in main-project.**

What is the best way? if am not using submodule or subtree. how can I achive this.

when I tried to clone a plugin  in to my main projects subfoler, it automaticaly convert to submodule. how to detach that plugin folder from the main project.

I tried to exclude using gitignore, but that fails.

Does anyone have an Idea about this situation?

Comment: Consider keeping them as two separate repos and use `npm link`.

Comment: "when I tried to clone a plugin in to my main projects subfoler, it automaticaly convert to submodule." <-- This is not standard behavior. If you do `git clone plugins` from your `main-pro` worktree root folder, git will just clone it. Make sure you've cleaned up all remains of the submodule setup though, i.e. do a `git rm`, and remove `.gitmodules`/`.git/modules/....` for good measure.